# EJS: Hide div when data is passed from Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am in a situation, where if data is passed, i want to hide a div and display the data.

This is the code:

```
        <div class="container">
            <!-- If data exists, handle them -->
            <ul>
                <% if (locals.data) { %>
                    <script language="javascript">
                        var x = document.getElementById("Error");
                        x.style.display = "none";
                    </script>
                    <% data.forEach(function(dat) { %>
                        <li><%= dat %></li>
                    <% }); %>
                <% } %>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I manage to pass the data, but the error message remains there.
The data i pass are then rendered, according to the EJS script.
How can i hide the div with `id="Error"`?

EDIT: This is the div i want to remove

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center container" id="Error">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center container">
                        <h2 class="text-center">There are no STL models!</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
```

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with css, inspect that div in your browser and check if display none is applied.

Comment: I don't have CSS for that element. I only have : body { padding-top:80px; word-wrap:break-word; } AND form { text-align: center; }

Comment: Did you checked if that code is hiding that error when you run it in browser?

Comment: I didn't understand what you just said, sorry...

Comment: Open console in your browser when that page is loaded. And paste `var x = document.getElementById("Error");` `x.style.display = "none";`

Comment: I get this: var x = document.getElementById("Error");
undefined
x.style.display="none";
"none"
The rendering of the div remains.

Comment: For the first command it outputs 'undefined', for the second 'none'.

Comment: I edited the question with the HTML code for the div i want to remove.

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(document.getElementById("Error"))`

Comment: @kmgt It got solved with the question i accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x.style.display = "none";` Doesn't work because bootstrap is overwriting that property.
Use `x.classList.add('invisible')` instead. [Visibility in bootstrap.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/visibility/)